# Python - Selenium: Find / Click YT-Like Button

Tags: python, selenium, button, youtube

does anyone of you know how to find / click the YT-Like button in Python using selenium since it doesn't have a real Id, etc...

Thanks for the answers

Comment: use a CSS selector or Xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select with CSS Selector like this:

if you want to `like`:

`#watch8-sentiment-actions > span > span:nth-child(1) > button`

if you want cancel `like`:

`#watch8-sentiment-actions > span > span:nth-child(2) > button`

Comment: Ouuuuu man you are awesome, I searched for a solution almost like an hour but it seems like I didn't use the "find_by_css..." correctly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: you can use `find_element_by_css_selector`.

Comment: if you're using Chrome, you can use Chrome's inspector to find element's selector or xpath!

Comment: Yes of course I did it and it worked but I meant that I didn't use it correctly until you posted that :)